# Specify correlation matrix for generating correlated binary variables

Tags: r, correlation

I would like to create correlated binary variables from a pre-specified correlation matrix, where the majority of varialbes are highly correlated and some of the variables are relatively uncorrelated.

For example my correlation matrix would be:

```
cor.mat<-matrix(0.8,nrow=50,ncol=50)
cor.mat[,sample(1:50,10)]<-0.2
diag(cor.mat) <- 1
```

Then I would use rmvbin:

```
library(bindata)
rmvbin(100, margprob=rep(.6,50), bincorr=cor.mat)
```

However, in this case I get `NaNs` as output because sigma is not positive definite.

How can I specify a correlation matrix that fulfils my criteria (i.e. majority of high correlation and minority of low correlation)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about applied math/statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your correlation matrix should be symetric. that means that if you take everything below the diagonal it is the same as the mirror image of everything above the diagonal. This has to be the case for correlation matrices because the correlation of xi and xj should be the same as the correlation of xj and xi.

I will make a 11x11 matrix because I dont want to type your 50x50 matrix. the high correlation part would look like this.

```
1  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8
.8  1  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8
.8 .8   1  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8
.8 .8  .8   1  .8  .8  .8  .8
.8 .8  .8  .8   1  .8  .8  .8
.8 .8  .8  .8  .8   1  .8  .8 
.8 .8  .8  .8  .8  .8   1  .8
.8 .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8   1
```

That is the matrix for your first 8 vars. Then add on 3 more that have low correlation with the 8 you have and each other.

```
 1  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .2  .2  .2
.8   1  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .2  .2  .2
.8  .8   1  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .2  .2  .2
.8  .8  .8   1  .8  .8  .8  .8  .2  .2  .2
.8  .8  .8  .8   1  .8  .8  .8  .2  .2  .2
.8  .8  .8  .8  .8   1  .8  .8  .2  .2  .2
.8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8   1  .8  .2  .2  .2
.8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8  .8   1  .2  .2  .2
.2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2   1  .2  .2 
.2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2   1  .2 
.2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2  .2   1
```

This matrix can be divided into 4 parts. The part with the correlation among just the highly correlated variables x1 through x8, that is the upper left part. The part with just the correlation among the lowly correlated variables x9 through x11, the bottom right. Finally the upper right and the lower left are the correlation between the three and the eight. These two have to be each others transpose.

There are many ways to build this matrix in R.

```
cormat=matrix(.8,nrow=11,ncol=11)
cormat[,9:11]=.2  #set the right columns
cormat[9:11,]=.2  #set the bottom rows
diag(cormat)=1     #set the diagonal
```

If you are worried that the matrix is not positive definite just check that the eigenvalues are all postive with

```
eigen(cormat)$values
```

Comment: thank you for your help. this doesn't seem to solve the fact that sigma is not positive definite. I'm searching for a matrix that fulfils this criteria.

Comment: The matrix above is positive definite. I also think it conforms to your other requirements above.

Comment: I added some syntax to check that the matrix was in fact pos-def, so you can check yours to make sure.